# Tips for querying dynamic object fields in Crate

Tags: wildcard, crate

I have a table such as the one at the end of this question. I insert into the peers_array field a dynamically keyed array/object such as:

```
{
    "130":{
        "to":5
    },
    "175":{
        "fr":0
    },
    "188":{
        "fr":0
    },
    "190":{
        "to":5
    },
    "280":{
        "fr":4
    }
}
```

I'm looking for advice on how to wildcard query the key field. Such as:

```
select * from table where peers_array[*]['to'] > 10
```

In Elasticsearch I can query like this:

```
peers_array.*.to: >10
```

My Table:

```
CREATE TABLE table (
      "id" long primary key,
      "sourceRouteId" integer,
      "rci" integer,
      peers_array object(dynamic),
      "partition_date" string primary key
    ) partitioned by (partition_date) with (number_of_replicas = 0, refresh_interval = 5000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to say, but this is currently not possible. We'll put it on our backlog. Thanks for reporting this use case.